# plotting inside C++

Tags: c++, variables, opencv, plot

I am trying to plot variables in C++ inside a for loop. In Matlab, it is very easy, just type plot(x,y), but I do not know how to use it in C++. Is it possible to do it with opencv? or if anybody has a better recommendation I really appreciate it.

Comment: You need to find plotting library for C++. Like this one http://qwt.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [cvplot](http://code.google.com/p/cvplot/) library, it will provide matlab style plotting function in opencv. You can also use [this](http://www.shervinemami.info/graphs.html) library.

Comment: unfortunately both links use the deprecated c-api (which won't be supported for long)

Comment: I read the cvplot website, but there are not any information how to use it. Furthermore, even wiki tab is empty, no explanation. Do you know where I can find some explanation about it?

Comment: You just have to include the cvplot header(# include<cvplot.h>) file in your .cpp or .c file. for details you can check [this] (http://code.google.com/p/cvplot/source/browse/cvplot.cpp). Unfortunately i am not aware of any websites that give theoretical details on how to use cvplot.

Comment: Folks who just read this post, do not forget to include the source file for compilation too

Answer (score 1):

If you want high quality plots take a look at [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) (can be used from C++ program) or [asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/) (you can generate script and use this script for render your plot), but these tools are not for dynamic plotting.